# on key press check pattern for HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a input which is of type **text**. On its keypress I am calling the below code:

```
         function checkHHMMformat(evt, a)
         {
           var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
           var isValid = /^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$/.test(key);
           if (!isValid)
           {
             event.preventDefault();
             return false;
           }
           return true;
         }
```

But I'm not able to validate it properly

Comment: Your `key` is a single character, your pattern is for the whole input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expression to Validate Time Format HH:MM:SS 24-hour should be as shown below:

```
 /(?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d):(?:[012345]\d)/gm
```